# Rails 3.1 has_many, :through => not working (joined model returns nil)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-many-through

**Update**: This was all due to a stupid error: previously, I had defined a method with the same name as one of the methods ActiveRecord creates, which was masking the proper behaviour and breaking everything. I can't answer/close the question for a few more hours, apologies to anyone who looked into this!

I have an infuriating problem with a `has_many, :through =>` relationship in my Rails 3.1 app.

It is infuriating because as far as I can see it is identical to two similar relationships which both work.

The owner of these relationships declares them like this:

```
has_many :user_skills, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :skills, :through => :user_skills
has_many :user_roles, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles
has_many :conversation_users
has_many :conversations, :through => :conversation_users
```

(I am aware I have not followed standard nomenclature for join tables here - I only read about the convention of both-plural, names-alphabetical after setting this up, and I will refactor later)

The first two pairs of relationships (skills and roles) work just fine.

The final relationship (conversations) does not work fully. `user.conversation_users` returns the expected array, but `user.conversations` returns `nil`. Not an empty array, `nil`.

I may well be doing something stupid here, so I would be very grateful to anyone who can spot something wrong with the `ConversationUser` or `Conversation` models below.

**conversation_user.rb**

```
class ConversationUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :conversation_users
  belongs_to :conversation, :inverse_of => :conversation_users

  validates_presence_of :user
  validates_presence_of :conversation
end
```

**conversation.rb**

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :conversation_users, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :conversation_users

  validates_presence_of :unique_id
end
```

(I am also aware that these are not really complex enough to justify `has_many, :through =>` over `has_and_belongs_to_many`, but planned additional functionality will require join models.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answering to close question**:

This was all due to a stupid error: previously, I had defined a method with the same name as one of the methods ActiveRecord creates, which was masking the proper behaviour and breaking everything.